# Connecting to SQL Server over network using ADO from Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, ado, vba

I need to connect to a SQL Server DB running on my laptop from another computer on a network. I am doing this both from a C# app as well as in a VBA macro. Both run perfectly on my laptop and the C# app runs perfectly over the network. However I cannot connect using VBA over the network. This is my connection string:

`ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MY-LAPTOP; DAtabase=SAFEXlive; UID = MyUsername; PWD=MyPassword"`

Aside from the 'Driver={SQL Server}' this is the same as the connection string I am using in the C# app which works.

I am then using the following code (With a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library in VBE) to open the connection:

```
Dim oConnection As Connection
Set oConnection = New Connection
oConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
oConnection.Open
```

This works correctly if I run it on my laptop but if I run it on another computer on the network I get the error: "Run-time error '-2147217843 (80040e4d) [Microsoft][ODBC Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user..." and the user it specifies it the windows log in for the computer.

Are there some security settings I need to set in code or in excel? Or am I constructing the connection string incorrectly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While I am not sure what is causing your error. I can say that I don'think there is anything wrong with your connection string. You seem to be connecting ok, but the server is rejecting your login.

Comment: And it is telling me the user is the windows log-in... any idea how I can troubleshoot this? I think the issue is it is trying to connect to sql-server using the windows login instead of the UID and password in the connection string - am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this will help, but just guessing: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/1bb10896-27ed-4469-81e0-a84f4fba68c9

Comment: Thanks for the comment - but I'm not sure what you're suggesting. That question uses a C# app to connect using integrated security. I need to connect from an excel app using whatever the opposite of integrated security is called. Are you saying this could be a firewall issue...?

Comment: upon further reflection i wonder if the vba driver interface is trying to use some level windows file sharing type security. does the other computer have full access to the laptop?

Comment: @Pynner, I think this is on the right track. It looks as though because there was a leading space in my username, it decided to use the windows security instead. Highly frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. The answer is rather infuriating. The problem is in fact with the connection string, with the UID. Believe it or not changing `...UID= MyUsername;...` to `..UID=MyUsername;...`, i.e. removing the space character, was all it took! Thanks for suggestions though.

Comment: I do believe it, that was my answer.

Comment: Your answer changed the Driver={SQL Server} to Provider=SQLOLEDB which was a far more noticeable change than the space and did not work for me.

Comment: next time use a Trim() function ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this Connection string,

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MY-LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=SAFEXlive;User ID=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword"
```

Is this an AD Domain login? Make sure you have appended the domain to the username e.g, `domain\user` . 
I suggest using integrated security instead of this.